# Proving $\langle f,f \rangle =0 \implies f=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

Let $Y=C[0,1]$, prove that $\langle f,g \rangle = \int _0^1 f(x)g(x)dt$ is an inner product.

Just need to talk about the condition on the title. 
Can we simply say $<f,f>=0$ so $||f||=0$ so by definition of norms, this means $\iff f=0$ which proves the statement?

Comment: There are [properties that an inner product satisfies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition).  Show that $\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\,dx$ with $f$ and $g$ continuous on $[0,1]$ satisfy those properties.

Comment: I understand that there are like three properties, I just need advice on the first property. Showing that $<f,f> \ge 0$ and $<f,f> =0 \implies f=0$

Comment: Show that $\int_0^1 f^2(x)\,dx=0\implies f=0$ when $f\in C[0,1]$.

Comment: @Dr.MV Can I say let $ F(t)= \int _0^t f(x)^2 dx$ so by the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have $F'(t)=f(t)^2=0$ so f(t)=0 for all t in 0 to 1?

Comment: Hmm.. nice argument. But we only know $F(1)=0$.

Comment: @snowman The condition only tells you that $F(1)=0$.

Comment: How do you  know that $F'(t)=f^2(t)=0$?  We are not given $F(t)=0$ for all $t$; we are given that $F(1)=0$.

Comment: @Dr.MV F(t) is a constant function. Doesn't work here either way as you can see by the comments :(

Comment: @Berci Can you explain why it is only for F(1)=0 please? I am asking because if we had to prove $\int_a^b |f(x)|dx=0 \implies f=0$ for $f \in C[a,b]$, then we can do this method: Let $F(t)= \int_a^t |f(x)|dx=0$ then by fund thm of cal, $F'(t)=0=|f(t)|$. If it works for that, then why doesn't it work in our case now?

Comment: How do you know that it is a constant function?  We don't know a priori, that $F(t) = 0$ for any value of $t$ other than $1$.  It's derivative is $f^2(t)$, but we don't know a priori that this is zero; we're trying to prove that. So, your approach doesn't work unfortunately.  But, it was a good try.  So, well done for that!  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV hmmm could you comment on what I said before your last comment please. I am still not seeing why F(t)=0 for only t=1...

Comment: @snowman *By your definition*, $F(1)=\int_{0}^{1} |f(x)|^{2} dx = 0$. We do not know **anything** (yet) about $\int_{0}^{t}|f(x)|^{2} dx$ for other values of $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By properties of integrals, $\langle f,f\rangle = 0$ implies
$$
    0 \le \int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|^2dt \le \int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|^2dt+\int_{x}^{1}|f(t)|^2dt
    = \int_{0}^{1}|f(t)|^2dt = 0.
$$
Therefore, $\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|^2dt=0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. And $|f(t)|^2$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ because $f(t)$ is continuous. Therefore, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,
$$
     0 = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|^2dt = |f(x)|^2,\;\; 0 < x < 1.
$$
The right derivative at $0$ is $|f(0)|^2$, which must also be $0$; the left derivative at $1$ is $|f(1)|^2$, which must also be $0$. So $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: How did you deduce the last part? Why was it when i tried it this way it never worked? Its in the comments. Please help.

Comment: @snowman : What last part is that? Do you mean the derivative of the integral is the integrand when the integrand is continuous? That's the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Or do you mean something else? I like this solution because it uses only properties of the integral, without $\epsilon-\delta$.

Comment: The very last paragraph you wrote about the derivatives. How did you deduce those facts?

Comment: @snowman : The proof of the Fundamental Theorem actually shows it. You could also extend the function to be $|f(0)|^2$ to the left of $0$ and conclude it from the Fundamental Theorem directly because the integral on the extended part doesn't show up in the right hand derivative at $0$ anyway. Alternatively, if you don't like these techniques, you can conclude that $|f(t)|^2=0$ for $0 < t < 1$ and then conclude that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ by continuity of $f$.

Comment: So could you tell me when this method fails to work please?

Comment: @snowman This method is very general. Even if you assume the function to be Lebesgue measurable and not necessarily continuous, you're able to use this technique to show that the function $f$ is $0$ a.e. by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem. This is a rather general technique for showing $\int_{0}^{1}|f(t)|^2dt=0 \implies f=0$.

Comment: Does the function have to be in modulus signs though?

Comment: @snowman : I'm used to dealing with complex functions, and that notation works for real or complex. For real, $f$, the expression $f(t)^2$ is equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

Ah, but how do you know $||f||=<f,f>$ defines a norm? That requires a proof too!

Suppose $f\ne 0$. Then we can find $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x) \ne 0$. So $f(x)>0$ or $f(x)<0$. In either case, $f(x)^{2}>0$. But since $f$ is continuous at $x$, for any $\epsilon>0$ we can choose $\delta$ sufficiently small that if $|y-x|<\delta$, $|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. In particular, we can keep $f(y)^{2}>0$ on a small interval. Can you bound the integral of $f(y)^{2}$ on this small interval? What does it tell you about the integral over the whole of $[0,1]$?

Comment: Well, if you do assume it then the fact is trivial. But someone, somewhere has to prove it! As we note above, the condition only tells you that $F(1)=0$, not that $F(t)=0$ for all $t$.

Comment: for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \overline{g(x)} dx$  be an inner product on the vector space of functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$, we have to prove that it is bilinear, complex symmetric, and that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|^2  dx$ is a norm (i.e. that $\|f\| \ge 0$, that $\|f\| = 0 \implies f= 0$ and $\|f+g\| \le \|f\| + \|g\|$ and that $\|a f\| = |a| \ \|f\|$), once this is done, we can write it $\langle f,g\rangle$ (we proved it is an inner product) and hence $\langle f,f\rangle = 0 \implies f = 0$ we already proved it !

Comment: @DanielLittlewood In class, we proved that the norm induced by the inner product is a norm. Such that $||x||=<x,x>^{1/2}$. Say if we were allowed to refer to this, would it then be trivial?

Comment: But you haven't proved it's an inner product yet! Think about it this way: suppose you're trying to convince someone who doesn't believe you that $<f,g>$ is an inner product or that $<f,f>$ is a norm. Try to prove the statement without assuming **either** of those facts.

Comment: Ok so f is continuous at x so for all epsilon, there exists delta>0 s.t. |f(x)-f(y)|<e whenever |x-y|<delta. The stuff you said after that, i am having trouble understanding. Another def of continuity is limf(x) =f(y) as x tends to y. So are u saying if we look at the right hand limit, f(y) will be strictly positive?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood I'm the \langle \rangle fairy, here to let you know that $\langle, \rangle$ plays nicer with TeX than <, > does :)

Answer (score 1):

Note that you need to know that $\|f\|=\sqrt{\langle f,f\rangle}$ is a norm to use it. But to prove that $\|f\|$ is a norm implies to prove that $\|f\|=0\Rightarrow f=0$, and prove this is equivalent to prove what you need to prove. So you are using what you want to prove to prove it! So what you did is not a good idea.

Suppose that $\langle f,f\rangle =0$, that is, $\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx =0$, and let $h=f^2$, so $h(x)\geq 0$ for every $x\in [0,1]$. Suppose that $h(a)> 0$ for some $a\in [0,1]$. As $h$ is continuous, you can find an open interval $I=]a-\epsilon , a+\epsilon[$ containing $a$ such that $h(x)>0$ for every $x\in I\cap [0,1]$. But then, writing $I\cap [0,1] = (\alpha,\beta)$ we have

$$ 0=\int_0^1 h(x)dx \geq \int_\alpha^\beta h(x)dx > 0,$$

an absurd. So $h(x)=0$ for every $x\in [0,1]$ and this implies that $f=0$.